# How to generate a random number between 1 and a million?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, random

I want to make a function the generates a random number from 1 to million .. 
and put it in a form of

```
"You have won [ random value ] points. Congratulations."
```

and somehow save it into variable "x" that i can call in a text box so in the text box value which like:

```
<input class="textbox1" type="text" readonly value="[X]"> 
<p> [X] </p>
<a href="mywebsite" data-text="[X]"></a>
```

So i can use it in different places, how could I do it ?

Comment: use `array_rand` or `rand` of PHP functions...

Comment: You want to do this using `php` or `js`?

Comment: If there was an error (since you asked again), you could just notify me in here, there was no need to create new question about the same thing. You may also accept the answer as it really has no syntax errors and does what you asked for. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generate random number between 1 and 1 million and save in $randnumber;
Then echo the sentence. Finally, show that number in HTML by inserting PHP code:

```
//...
$randnumber = rand(1, 1000000);

echo "You have won ".$randnumber." points. Congratulations.";
?>

<input class="textbox1" type="text" value="<?= $randnumber ?>" readonly> 
<p> <?= $randnumber ?> </p>
<a href="mywebsite" data-text="<?= $randnumber ?>">Text</a>
```

I think there are no syntax errors.

Answer (score 6):

In Javascript you can use:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
```

This will generate a number between 1 and 1 million.

A snippet to test:

```js
console.log(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1));
```

Comment: how to separate random number result with point or comma?

Answer (score 2):

use php function rand()

```
rand(1, 1000000);
```

Comment: Its already [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37476390/5447994) by Edvin Tenovim

Answer (score 1):

Use this if want better random numbers:

```
echo mt_rand(5, 15);
```

or visit here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php